# Tips for speed-running

Tags: assassins-creed-3

As you might have known, I can have only 2 convoys on my first save due to a glitch.

 I want to speed-run through a new save to get all 3 convoys.

Do you guys have any tips for speed-running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Do only the main objectives for each story mission.
2. do not worry about side missions and item collection.

You can go back and complete the above after you get your 3rd convoy.

3. Murder guards instead of spending large amounts of time to sneak around them, when given the option. When your notoriety goes up just bribe the town crier. You should still sneak when possible, but don't get carried away with it.
4. climbing buildings and trees isn't the answer. Unlike in previous AC games, the rooftops are not an efficient way to get around in cities.
5. in open combat, kill enemies with guns. I like to disarm the weak enemies and use their muskets on the difficult ones. I hear that smokebombs+hidden blade is effecient for killing large groups, the only limiting factor is the number of bombs you can carry.
6. fast travel